# Add a couple of custom majorUnit labels in addition to existing labels on a Gauge control

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, gauge

I'm trying to setup a [Gauge control](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/radialgauge) using KendoUI 2020.1.114. It is showing up perfect out-of-the-box, but of course need to customize it.

Say for instance the scale's min is 100, max is 1000 and minorUnit is 50. This means starting from 100, every 50th unit will represent a "tick" or a small line.

How do I add a custom majorUnit label at, say, 235? Something like a major milestone. In other words you have the gauge going 150, 200, 250, 300, but you ALSO have a 235, and a label next to it that can say "Last year's sales"

Comment: The gauge control does not support custom tick marks or reference lines.  If you were really hardcore, you could decipher the svg elements that the component generates and insert your own `path` elements corresponding to the customizations you want.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really hardcore :) here is an example from Telerik team: https://dojo.telerik.com/@bubblemaster/OxUVeSur and the feature request (please upvote!) https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-jquery-ui/1357929-it-would-be-really-great-if-we-could-specify-a-label-for-a-range-in-a-gauge

Comment: The link to the bubblemaster Dojo is helpful and way easier than going into svg.